# Not able to send pictures to telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have a simple telegram code to send text and image.

```
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot('********:*********')

bot.sendMessage(chat_id=chat_id, text='hello')
bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\Wallpapers\\alley-89197_1920.jpg')
```

For a while i was able to atleast send the text but now I am getting the following error:

```
Unauthorized: Forbidden: bot can't send messages to bots
```

Could you please advise why I am getting this error?

Comment: Please change your token immediately

Comment: It was a changed token. The real token is much longer in length. Thanks

Comment: Great. Regarding the question: you probably trying to send a photo to the chat with another bot (or even the same?). Try sending message to a chat with some person (for example, write something to your bot from your personal account), and get the `chat_id` from bot updates, then use this chat_id instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the official FAQ: https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots

TL;DR: Telegram bots can't talk to other Telegram bots.